# Hide certain entries by default when using ActiveRecord finder methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In some of my models, I want to have a deleted/inactive flag. 99% of the time I am not interested in model objects that have this flag, and it's easy to forget excluding entries with that flag, so my question is this:

Is there any nice way of excluding these by default when using the `ActiveRecord` finder methods, like `where`, `find` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in your model definition:

```
default_scope :conditions => { :deleted => true }
```

But, if you want more flexibility, you can use [Paranoia](https://github.com/radar/paranoia), which aliases destroy actions and also implements the default scope, amongst other things.

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks! For anyone else dropping by, note that the first "=>" should be removed.

Comment: Oops.. Fixed it now for future reference.